# Binding values in repeater ,regarding the selection of first Column in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to bind the values in the repeater control where I have 4 columns, in the 2 drop-down and 2 text boxes.

My requirement is when I select the first drop-down in first column depending on that selection, balance 3 columns should be get Bind in the repeater in the same row.

**for eg**

In First column **DropDown**, when I select the `EmployeeName`, next **3columns(AGE,NO,ADDRESS)** in the same row in the repeater should be filled automatically.

```
 protected void ddlEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (EHSIMSDataContext db = new EHSIMSDataContext(EHSIMSConnectionString.GetConnectionString()))
    {
    (((sender as DropDownList).Parent).FindControl("email") as TextBox).Text =  ;
    (((sender as DropDownList).Parent).FindControl("Depart") as TextBox).Text = "Age";

    }
}
```

Repeater Control

```
 protected void rptactions_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

        DropDownList ddlemployee = e.Item.FindControl("ddlemployee") as DropDownList;
      using (EHSIMSDataContext db = new EHSIMSDataContext(EHSIMSConnectionString.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            List<EMPLOYEE> objlistemp = (from ct in db.EMPLOYEEs
                                         orderby ct.FIRSTNAME
                                         select ct).ToList<EMPLOYEE>();
            ddlemployee.Items.Clear();
            ddlemployee.Items.Add(new ListItem("--SELECT--", ""));
            foreach (EMPLOYEE emp in objlistemp)
            {
                ddlemployee.Items.Add(new ListItem(emp.FIRSTNAME, emp.EMPLOYEE_ID.ToString()));
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way for the scenario you mentioned..

```
protected void ddlEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (((sender as DropDownList).Parent).FindControl("txtAge") as TextBox).Text = "Age";
}
```

Likewise, you can find other controls as well...

Note: In the aspx file, you need to add `OnSelectedIndex` changed event to this DropDownList control in the Repeater and should also set it's `AutoPostBack` property to `True`

**Update:**

If your model class looks as below

```
class Employee
{
     public int ID {get; set};
     public int Age {get; set};
     public string Name {get; set};
     public string Address {get; set};
}
```

If you have a list of Employees in an object `lstEmployees` (of type `List<Employee>`), you can retrieve Name of the Employee having an `ID` of `employeeID` of using the following query

```
lstEmployees.Find(e => e.ID == employeeId).Name
```

Of course, you always need to perform all kind of null checks before you try to read the property which otherwise could result in `NullReferenceException` in case no match is found.

Comment: Hi..its working fine but i need not to hardcore anyvalues as yu did.In the text i need to bind the value of the emplyee from his table.

Comment: Yes!! That is understandable. I thought you have concerns getting the respective handle. So I just posted this code. If you need how to get appropriate values; you can accomplish through a LINQ Query..

Comment: Sorry i coulnt get yu.

Comment: Can yu please tellme the syntax of Linq for this concept

Comment: where can i use this statement
lstEmployees.Find(e => e.ID == employeeId).Name

Comment: In the event handler for dropdownlist box. Once you identify the control, control's SelectedValue or SelectedItem property (based on your implementation) will give your Employee Name or ID. Based on this you can get the respective values from your DataSource. For a more precise answer, you need to share the code that helps us understand what you are binding to your repeater control.

Comment: I HAVE POSTED THE CODE IN THE ABOVE.

Comment: You should post that piece of code, where you assign a datasource to your repeater control.

Comment: :here its the datasource for the repeatere.

Comment: If employeeID is the Employee ID of the selected employee in the dropdown, _from e in db.Employees where e.EmployeeID = employeeID select e.Age_ will give you the Age of the selected employee.